# cs50 pset1 cash.c expected expression

Tags: c, while-loop, syntax-error, cs50, logical-and

I finished writing my code for cash.c, but I'm unable to compile it. There's an 'expected expression' error for every one of my **<** at the *//least amount of coins to make a certain amount of change* section. I tried changing it a couple of times, and even look up what the hell I'm doing wrong but I can't find anything. Can someone please help me? Also, I'd love to hear any advice or feedback about my code! The code is down below.

Thank you!
Aleena <3

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    // prompt user for non-negative input & convert dollars to cents
    float change;
    int cents;
    do
    {
        change = get_float("How much change? ");
        cents = round(change * 100);
    }
    while (change < 0);

    //least amount of coins to make certain amount of change
    int coins;
    coins = 0;
    while (cents >= 0.25)
    {
        coins++;
        cents = cents - 25;
    }
    while (cents >= .1 && < 0.25)
    {
        coins++;
        cents = cents - 10;
    }
    while (cents >= .05 && < .1)
    {
        coins++;
        cents = cents - 5;

    }
    while (cents >= 0.01 && < .05)
    {
        coins++;
        cents = cents - 1;
    }
    printf("%i\n", coins);
}
```

I'm also wondering if it's normal that I'm having a hard time with cs50? I understand everything in the lectures and shorts, but the problem sets seem to be taking me a very long time. It took me like 3 weeks to complete mario.c, and I can't do them without Googling something. It's making me question if I should even be listening to this course without any experience. I'm really enjoying this course, but do you think I should take it down a notch and start with something a bit more beginner friendly?

Comment: I personally wouldn't start programming with C – a higher level language such as Python is so much easier to get to grips with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters such a condition

```
 while (cents >= 0.25)
```

in any case does not make a sense because the variable `cents` is declared as having the type `int`.

```
int cents;
```

It seems you mean

```
 while (cents >= 25 )
```

In other while loops you have a syntax error as for example in this while loop

```
while (cents >= .1 && < 0.25)
```

You need at least to write

```
while (cents >= 10 && cents < 25)
```

But when the control reaches this while loop the variable `cents` already has a value that is less than `25` due to the preceding while loop. So it is enough to write

```
while ( cents >= 10 )
```

So your loops can look like

```
while ( cents >= 25 )
{
    coins++;
    cents = cents - 25;
}
while ( cents >= 10 )
{
    coins++;
    cents = cents - 10;
}
while ( cents >= 5 )
{
    coins++;
    cents = cents - 5;

}
while (cents >= 1 )
{
    coins++;
    cents = cents - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to repeat `cents` in each of those "between" comparisons:

```
    // Wrong: while (cents >= .1 && < 0.25)
    while (cents >= .1 && cents < 0.25) ...
    // Wrong: while (cents >= .05 && < .1) ...
    while (cents >= .05 && cents < .1) ...
    // Wrong: while (cents >= 0.01 && < .05) ...
    while (cents >= 0.01 && cents < .05) ...
```